# Can I mark sms as read in the notification menu?

Tags: sms, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5

When get an incoming sms and view it in the notification menu (swiping down from the top of the screen) I can sometimes read the entire message there and I don't need to reply to it. Is it possible to mark it as read there and then? The two options I have right now is "reply" and "call".

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 with android 4.2.2

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed you can! It's not a 'stock' or 'Hangouts' feature though, but there are apps that can perform this functionality.

[SMS notifier on the](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.probcomp.smsnotifier&hl=en)  Google Play store has this option as you will see in the screenshots for it.

Off the record a friend said that Google tend to prefer you to Activate something, rather than mark as read! That's why you don't see this option very much.

As per bmdixon: This does not work in Hangouts. It seems OK if hangouts is not the default SMS application, but this may vary between Android Versions and OEM devices.

Comment: Good suggestion but worth noting that according to the 'What's new' section "...due to restrictions, messages cannot be marked as read in Hangout app." I expect this is more of an an issue with the SMS restrictions in 4.4 than Hangouts itself however.

Comment: @bmdixon I've added that caveat to the post now, many thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Hoerver, unfortunately the app is not compatible with Galaxy S5. I will look around for other apps though...

Comment: And what to do with android > 4.2