# Is there a way to permanently clear all notifications and mark them as "read" from the lock screen or notification menu?

Tags: sms, notifications, notification-bar

Background: I often get no signal on my phone, so use apps like Airdroid and O2 TuGo which allow for texting and calling over wifi and from multiple devices.

The problem is, when I get my signal back, I suddenly get a flood of text messages which take a long time to individually mark as read. I also get message/call notifications from apps like TuGo even if I've already read the message from another device such as a desktop PC or tablet.

Is there a way I can **permanently** clear the notifications, preferably from the lock screen and/or the notifications bar?

A search leads to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/80728/can-i-mark-sms-as-read-in-the-notification-menu) question but it only applies to SMS messages, not other notifications.

Android's own "clear all" button does not mark notifications as read, it only temporarily removes them which is pretty useless.

Comment: Marking texts as read is a per-app thing, so there's no standard way to do it. By 'permanently' clearing notifications, do you mean disabling all notifications entirely (for a period of time or for ever)?

Comment: @JoshHolland I meant clearing only that instance of a notification permanently. E.g. banish a missed call alert, but don't forbid any more missed call alerts from occuring in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have some solutions.

1. To avoid apps permanently not to display in notification bar.

Go in app info of particular app and disable show notifications.

2. To read all SMS at once.

Install Tetra SMS from play store .This app gives option to mark as read to all SMS

Comment: Could you link the app?